# Change environment in sentry at runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, sentry

In my flutter App I can change the environment dynamically. Therefore I would like to change the environment accordingly for the crash tracking with sentry.

Is there a way to change the environment at runtime?

I just found [`SentryFlutter.init(...)`](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/configuration/environments/), but that doesn't seem to make sense to me to update the environment.